# Allowing anyone clone a Git repository in TFS 2018

Tags: git, tfs

In TFS 2018 (Specifically, I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server
Version 16.131.27701.1), is there a way to allow anyone clone a GIT repository just like a public repository? BitBucket allows this, but I can't find a way to do this in TFS/Git. I'm basically trying to allow anyone in my company to get the library code without asking them to create an account in TFS - TFS server is within the company network, hence there's no security concern.

Comment: Your TFS is not connected to the Active Directory?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not connected to the active directory. It's hosted in an isolated environment within the company network with different domain name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

You didn't mention if there is a two-way trust between the two domains? If it is, users from your existing work domain can pretty much be able to connect to your TFS server with different domain just by specifying the domain and users when authenticating.

Take a look at this related official tutorial: [Trusts and Forests Considerations for Team Foundation Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms253081(v=vs.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Besides, you could also directly move your TFS sever, change domain.

This following documentation gives a good detailed account on working across domains:  [Move from one environment to another for Azure DevOps on-premises](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/move-across-domains?view=azure-devops)

---

At present, no. TFS is not able to set a public code repository like GitHub/BitBucket.

> *I'm basically trying to allow anyone in my company to get the library
>   code without asking them to create an account in TFS - TFS server is
>   within the company network, hence there's no security concern.*

I'm afraid, there maybe some misunderstanding. You can add Windows user or Windows group in TFS. TFS use the authentication with windows user/ domain user(Active Directory) to access the server. **TFS can't create users directly**. There are no TFS own users.

> Additional: About the relationship with TFS and Active Directory
>
> TFS does **not** write to Active Directory (AD) **nor** "has it's own
>   Active Directory".
>
> TFS stores users and groups, permissions and security, into its own
>   database. To integrate with Windows Security by running a [background
>   job](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/architecture/background-job-agent)
>   every hour and *reading* users and groups from AD.

In your scenario, you just need to make sure users in your company already in your AD, and add them to TFS, finally **assign them corresponding permission** for team project and corresponding git repo.

End users do not need to do some extra operation such as create an account. They can use their own AD account/password to access TFS and git repo, then clone it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, it's not connected to the active directory. It's hosted in an isolated environment within the company network with different domain name. So someone has to create a Windows user.

Comment: @JerryHan  Instead of create a windows user. Then may have to maintain two accounts. You didn't mention if there is a two-way trust between the two domains? If it is, users from your existing work domain can pretty much be able to connect to your TFS server with different domain just by specifying the domain and users when authenticating. Details please see my update reply.